# specialized template struct as base struct

Tags: c++

I have looked around all the related questions but no luck. Maybe this is a little bit strange use case hence no one really discussed before.

I have a specialized template struct "base". Then I try to use a template struct "derived" inherited the base and use the member of it.

The code:

```
template <typename T>
struct base {
        char *type = "default";
};

// int base struct
template <>
struct base <int> { char *type="int"; };

// char base struct
template <>
struct base <char> { char *type="char"; };

// short base struct
template <>
struct base <short> { char *type="short"; };

template <typename T>
struct derived : base <T> {
   char n0 = type[0];    // get the first char of "type" in base
};


int main (int argc, char** argv) {

        struct derived<char> c_d;
        cout << c_d.n0 << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

The compilation error occurs

```
test.cpp:65:14: error: ‘type’ was not declared in this scope
    char n0 = type[0];
              ^~~~
```

If I specialized the "derived" struct as well, it works.

```
template <typename T>
struct derived;

template <>
struct derived <int> : base<int> { char n0 = type[0]; };

template <>
struct derived <char> : base<char> { char n0 = type[0]; };

template <>
struct derived <short> : base<short> { char n0 = type[0]; };
```

However, It seems silly to repeat the same code in the derived struct. My questions are, why am I getting error and is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: `char n0 = type[0];` -> `char n0 = this->type[0];`

Comment: @UnholySheep Hey this actually work! Can you explain why tho? Use "this" seems makes sense to me but I don't understand why after specializing the derived struct "this" it worked?

Comment: This is independent of the specialization itself, it is connected to nondependent name lookup in class templates. This page tries to explain it a bit better: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members